# Query list of keys having a specific lower-level key in a nested dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

My data looks like this:

```
data = {'Shop1': {'Fruit': {2021: 5},
      'Veggies': {2021: 10}},
     'Shop2': {'Veggies': {2021: 6}},
     'Shop3': {'Veggies': {2021: 4}},
     'Shop4': {'Meat': {2021: 8},
      'Veggies': {2021: 9},
      'Cheese': {2021: 6},
      'Sweets': {2021: 9},
      'Drinks': {2021: 15}}}}
```

`Shop1`, `Shop2`, `Shop3` and `Shop4`... are my primary keys whereas Fruit, Veggies and other products are my nested keys.
I'm trying to find a way to query this dictionary in order to display the list of shops with `Veggies` AND without `Fruit`. In this case, the result would be `['Shop2', 'Shop3', 'Shop4']`.

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Just a tip, you don't need to use `dict()` here. You can just make it equal the curly brackets (`data = {...}`)

Answer (score 2):

Use a simple list comprehension:

```
[k for k,d in data.items() if 'Veggies' in d and not 'Fruit' in d]
```

output: `['Shop2', 'Shop3', 'Shop4']`